# "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.JarLifecycleMapping" is not available

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

How do I deal with this m2e plugin problem with Eclipse:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Lifecycle mapping
>   "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.JarLifecycleMapping" is not available. To enable
>   full functionality, install the lifecycle mapping and run
>   Maven->Update Project Configuration.  pom.xml /vosao-web  line 11 Maven
>   Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Does anyone have fixed this issue? Or this plugin is simply not supported in Eclipse?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Today i had the same problem and found this page by google.

My solution to resolve the problem  right click on the project then click Maven > Update Project... then click OK. That´s all!

Comment: Today I installed java-8-oracle and tried to create java maven project, and getting same error. I did Maven > Update Project, but still error is there

Comment: Need to check "Force Update of Snapshot/Releases" to work properly

Answer (score 5):

that's what i did on STS to resolve this issue:

1) Right-click on your project, select Maven -> Disable Maven Nature.

2) Right-click on your project, select spring tools -> update maven dependencies

3) Right click on your Project and select “Configure -> Convert into Maven Project”

Comment: That worked with a restart of the sts... I really dont know what shit I f**d but thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Today I resolved this problem by running eclipse with the "-clean" option (hope it will help someone in the future)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick solution that worked for me:

1. Disable the maven nature of the project:

   - Right click on the project
   - Maven
   - Disable Maven Nature
2. Enable the maven nature of the project

   - Right click on the project
   - Configure
   - Convert to Maven Project

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is fixed for me after restarting eclipse.

Hope this helps too :-)

Answer (score 3):

only update project was not resolving the problem.

It forced update of snapshot/release and it works.

Comment: Right click on Project -> Maven -> Update Project... -> Force Update of Snapshot/Release.
Works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in spring tool suite(based on eclipse). I uninstalled completelly maven support and then installed it again. It helped!

Comment: What do you mean completely uninstall maven support? Do you mean in the project?

Comment: Not. You should do like so: Help --> About Eclipse(menu item) --> Installation Details --> You select all items that belong to m2e plugin and click Uninstall button.

Comment: Then You go to market place and search 'Maven Integratio for Eclipse' and install this. If you are using Spring Tool Suite then open dashboard and on page "Extensions" you select "Maven Integratio for Eclipse 1.1" and install it.

Answer (score 2):

I restart my STS. Then right click on the maven project -> Maven -> Update project

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project, select Maven -> Disable Maven Nature.
select Maven -> Update Project

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Restart STS Tool.Than update your maven projects.Working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is right click on Project, Maven -> Update Project -> Tick the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" box and press OK. Update project on its own did not resolve this for me, contrary to what is stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything that was mentioned here, but for me the solution was to *exclude the workspace and create a new one*.